# Why did NetBeans show incorrect auto-completion?

Tags: c++, netbeans, coding-style, methods

I had an exam yesterday for Programming I at the end of my first semester. It was pretty basic, except I made a really, really obscure mistake that I wanted to ask the more experienced people here about:

I basically had a class Library that contained a vector that contains elements of Loan* which contains a Customer and Book class. Kind of like this:

```
class Library
{
    vector<Loan*> loans_;
};

class Loan
{
    Customer *customer_;
    Book *book_;
};
```

I had a function which required going through all the initialized book objects and seeing which ones belonged to whom, like this:

```
Customer *getBorrower(Book *book)
{
    vector<Loan*>::iterator iter;

    for( iter = loans_.begin(); iter != loans_.end(); ++iter )
    {
        if( (*iter).getBook() == book )
            return (*iter).getCustomer();
        else
            continue;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This stumped me, because in the Netbeans 6.9 IDE the (*iter). showed me a list of all the methods of the Loan object.

I was just about to quit the exam when I loaded up VC++08 and it asked me if I didn't want to use `->` instead.

`(*iter)->getBook();` worked to my chagrin.

So my question is:  why did the IDE allow me to use `.` and even spit out a list of the methods as well as for `->`? To my knowledge, it doesn't do this kind of madness anytime else. What exactly happened here? I'm not understanding what I tried to make the method do that gave me that weird netbeans error "Is not of type Loan*"

Second question: This is a style question. I commented to the professor about this, but he didn't seem too agreeable. The exam guidelines also had us create a public

`vector<Book*>` and `vector<Customer*>`.

We then accessed these from the main function to run our unit tests. I found this to be in extremely bad practise since a simple getter function would have provided us with what we needed without publicizing our information. Was I right to call this out as a bad design choice?

**Error:**

Library.cpp:14: error: request for member `getCustomer' in`(&iter)->__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<_Iterator, _Container>::operator* with _Iterator = Loan**, _Container = std::vector >', which is of non-class type `Loan*'

Comment: You seem to have left out the description of the error which "stumped you".

Comment: Oh crap! Thanks, I'll go fetch it!

Comment: I think IDE was telling you to do `iter->getBook()` not `(*iter)->getBook()` isn't it?

Comment: If it did I wouldn't have been stuck on that problem for over an hour. The error message wasn't that clear, unfortunately. Posted the error.

Answer (score 2):

The expression `(*iter)->getBook()` *should* work. The type `vector<T>::iterator` is something that "points to" an instance of `T`, and is usually a plain old `T*`. In your case, `T` is `Loan*`, so `T*` is `Loan**`. Thus `iter` is a `Loan**`, and so `(*iter)` is a `Loan*`, which you access using the `->` operator.

Quite possibly NetBeans got as confused as you did, though it has less of an excuse. :-)

Comment: Clearly, `(*iter)->getBook()` is correct.  I think the question is why NetBeans showed auto-completion for `(*iter).`, even though `(*iter)` is of type `Loan *`.

Comment: Exactly, Matthew pointed out the question, but thanks for the explanation! Always helps ^^

Comment: @Matthew: from the phrase, "worked to my chagrin," I got the impression that the OP thought the `->` syntax shouldn't work.

Comment: Yes, to my dismay. It was an obscure error and I spent about an hour pestering the professors overlooking the exam about the error until I noticed the error. Shame they didn't see it either.

Answer (score 2):

Well, it seems that Intellisense is just better than NetBeans. ;)

`(*iter)->getBook()` is the right way to get to the method in this case. Notice that iterator is kind of pointer with overloaded operators `*` and `->` to behave like ordinary pointer.

In your case, `*iter` is dereference of the element in vector, which is pointer. So, if you want to reach the method, you must use operator `->`, so the construction `(*iter)->getBook()` is valid. As well as more obfuscated method: `(*(*iter)).getBook()`.

Answer (score 1):

In C, `(*foo).bar` will follow the `foo` pointer to the foo struct and find the `bar` member. Because this is a tedious amount of typing, `foo->bar` was introduced to follow the `foo` pointer to the foo struct and find the `bar` member.

So you have to choose your use of `.` vs `->` based on whether you are working with a pointer to a structure or working with a structure.

Please note that I don't know how C++ has extended the use of `->` and `.` with classes, but since the first C++ implementations were based on C with structs, I *assume* that `->` and `.` work with classes the same way: objects of type `class` are dereferenced with `.` and objects of type `pointer to class` are dereferenced with `->`. But that's conjecture on my part.

Comment: I agree, but I don't understand why it allowed me to autocomplete with both `.` and `->` when I was actually working with the pointers which, as you correctly point out, need `->`

Comment: Most IDE environments differ from the compilers by a little too much... NetBeans probably did not follow your chain of templates and classes as well as Marcelo did.